# Why can't I set colspan for TH tag programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with thead with first th colspan = 1. I want to set it programmatically to value 2 : it doesn't work, how to do this ?

Here's source code :

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgof8m6q/

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col" colspan="1">TITLE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <td></td>    


        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript :

```
    var myTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var myThead = myTable.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0]; 
    _tr = myThead.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
    _th = _tr.getElementsByTagName("TH")[0]; 
    _th.colspan = 2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `colSpan`, not `colspan` ;-)

See [colSpan documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/DOM_Object/TableData/TableData_colSpan.htm).

([updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgof8m6q/5/)).

Comment: Since this could be solved by simply looking up the documentation - OP even knows what property exactly fails! - I am sorely tempted to close-vote for "simple typo error, unlikely to be useful to others".

Comment: @Jongware I'll second that.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript DOM elements has a special method for setting attributes, which is `setAttribute('<attribute>','<value>')`

```
_th.setAttribute("colspan", "2");
```

check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgof8m6q/7/